# Why is child component not rerendering in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I need help. Worked a lot with Vue and first encountered React.
I have a parent page component that has several child components (blocks with forms on the page). I ran into a problem, when changing the switch-toggle in the child component, the data must be sent to the parent component and the state must change there, and this state must be passed back to the child component via props. And the child component should change the switch-toggle. But it doesn't happen. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Page component (Parent)

```js
export default class SettingsPage extends Component<TProps, TState> {
  state: TState = {
    ...
    notifications: {
      allCustomerTransactions: true,
      ...
    },
    ...
  };

  ...

  onChangeNotifications = (field: keyof TNotifications, newValue: boolean): void => {
    this.setState((state) => {
      state.notifications[field] = newValue;
    });
  };

  ...

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        ...

        <Notifications
          className="cfx"
          onChange={ this.onChangeNotifications }
          notifications={ this.state.notifications }
        />
        <hr className="b h1 mv55 bgDADCE1"/>

        ...
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Notifications component (Child)

```js
export default class Notifications extends Component<TProps> {
  render() {
    const {className, notifications, onChange} = this.props;

    return (
      <section className={ className }>
        <div className="layoutRow fhaB fvaC">
          <div className="f23 fw7 lts0em c0 wsNW ov tov wmin0 fx1">Notifications</div>
        </div>

        <div className="mt26 (w1/2|pr58|w@m|lt)>1">
          <div>
            <FormItem
              name="Do you want to receive email notification for all customer transactions?"
              className="mb27"
              labelClasses="f12 fw4"
            >
              <SwitchB
                checked={ notifications.allCustomerTransactions }
                onChange={ (value) => {
                  onChange('allCustomerTransactions', value);
                } }
              />
            </FormItem>

            ...
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use currying function in your parent's onchange function. Read more: https://javascript.info/currying-partials

```
onChangeNotifications = (field: keyof TNotifications, newValue: boolean) => () => {
this.setState((state) => {
  state.notifications[field] = newValue;
});
```

};

Comment: I copied your example code, unfortunately it doesn't work either :(
The values ​​in the parent are updated when the switch is clicked, but the props itself, which is passed from parent to child, is not updated (if you somehow force the child to re-render after that, it will most likely work out)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution (although it seems to me that it looks a little crutch because the state is duplicated in the parent and child components, but it works quite well)

```js
export default class Notifications extends Component<TProps, TNotifications> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { ...this.props.notifications }; // <-- new line
  }

  render() {
    const {className, onChange} = this.props;

    return (
      ...
              <SwitchB
                checked={ this.state.allCustomerTransactions } // <-- changed
                onChange={ (value) => {
                  this.setState(() => ({ allCustomerTransactions: value })) // <-- changed
                  onChange('allCustomerTransactions', value);
                } }
              />
```